# How can I search through all of my files in the editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide, monaco-editor

In the updated Google Apps Script editor, there is no obvious way to search through all files, a basic IDE feature. In the past, I believe this was the default behavior. Can I accomplish this short of reverting to the legacy editor?

[image: New, less functional search dialog]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [deficiency known to Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176380828) in the upgraded editor and isn't possible other than using the old editor.

Until (if ever) Google fixes it, use [this (clunky but functional) extension.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/black-apps-script/lobpcflajoikohefjjdndofbfikadpfb)

Comment: From the same report mentioned above in the issue tracker report on May 18 22 there is a suggestion (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176380828#comment13) to use this chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/black-apps-script/lobpcflajoikohefjjdndofbfikadpfb

Comment: @jpp yes, I've been using it successfully for some time. It's clunky but gets the job done when needed.

Comment: The Black Apps extension is a real winner. To search multiple files, click the search icon (magnifying glass) after doing Ctrl-F (within the IDE, not the browser) and you can scroll through the pages it has found that match the search.

Answer (score 1):

There's current no way that I know of.  But you can select ctrl F and then select different files and check them individually